# Pairing observations in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

Let's take the following sample dataset:

```
counterparty1 <- c("A","B","B","B","B")
counterparty2 <- c("B","C","A","A","C")
counterparty1_side <- c("buy","sell","buy","sell","sell")
price <- c(1.2,3.7,2.5,1.2,3.7)
sample.data <- data.frame(counterparty1,counterparty2,counterparty1_side,price)
```

Rows 1 and 4 actually give identical observations - the only issue is that row 1 says that "A" buys the asset (implying that "B" sells) and in row 4 it says that "B" sells the asset (implying that "A" buys).

I'd like code to create the following dataset:

```
counterparty1 <- c("A","B","B","B","B")
counterparty2 <- c("B","C","A","A","C")
counterparty1_side <- c("buy","sell","buy","sell","sell")
price <- c(1.2,3.7,2.5,1.2,3.7)
transaction_number <- c(1,2,3,1,4)
duplicate <- c(1,0,0,1,0)
clean.data <- data.frame(counterparty1,counterparty2,counterparty1_side,price,transaction_number,duplicate)
```

In reality of course my dataset is much, much larger so I can't hard-code.

Update: I added row 5, which is identical to row 2, *including* the fact that counterparty 1 and 2 are in the same order. I want the "duplicate" variable to only flag rows 1 and 4 as duplicates (since they are inverses), not rows 2 and 5.

Comment: please, can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically, I have that transactions that can be reported by either or both counterparties. I'm trying to calculate aggregate volumes as well as learn other information about the transactions. However, I don't want aggregate volumes to double-count transactions that are reported by both counterparties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Updated Answer:

Addressing OP's follow up question, stating that if the very same transaction happens twice, it should not be picked up as duplicates.(for instance *party B* selling something to *party C* for *$3.7K* on two occasions); read the comments and updated question.

```r
library(dplyr)
sample.data %>% 
  mutate(transaction=if_else(counterparty1_side=="buy",
                             paste0(counterparty1,counterparty2),
                             paste0(counterparty2,counterparty1))) %>% 
  group_by_all %>% 
  mutate(dup_dum = 1:n()) %>% 
  group_by(transaction, dup_dum) %>% 
  mutate(transaction_number = group_indices(), 
         duplicate = +(n()!=n_distinct(transaction, dup_dum))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% select(-transaction, -dup_dum)

#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>   counterparty1 counterparty2 counterparty1_s~ price transaction_num~ duplicate
#>   <fct>         <fct>         <fct>            <dbl>            <int>     <int>
#> 1 A             B             buy                1.2                1         1
#> 2 B             C             sell               3.7                3         0
#> 3 B             A             buy                2.5                2         0
#> 4 B             A             sell               1.2                1         1
#> 5 B             C             sell               3.7                4         0
```

#### Original Answer:

Considering dupes (doesn't matter if they are dupes just because counter-party role has changed or they are actual dupes) (look at the edits to the question to see the first version of the question).

```r
library(dplyr)

sample.data %>% 
  mutate(transaction=if_else(counterparty1_side=="buy",
                             paste0(counterparty1,counterparty2),
                             paste0(counterparty2,counterparty1))) %>% 
  group_by(transaction) %>% 
  mutate(transaction_number = group_indices(), 
         duplicate = +(n()!=n_distinct(transaction))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% select(-transaction)

# # A tibble: 4 x 6
#  counterparty1 counterparty2 counterparty1_side price transaction_number duplicate
#  <fct>         <fct>         <fct>              <dbl> <int>              <int>
# 1 A             B             buy               1.2   1                  1
# 2 B             C             sell              3.7   3                  0
# 3 B             A             buy               2.5   2                  0
# 4 B             A             sell              1.2   1                  1
```

Comment: This looks great, except for one issue: it flags both repeated transaction as well as transactions that are dual-reported. For example, imagine that row 2 was repeated, but it was repeated because the transaction was actually executed twice. I want the code to flag that rows 1 and 4 are duplicates but not that the repeated row 2 is a duplicate.

Comment: @H.Z they also have the same price? Meaning row 2 is exactly same as row 1?

Comment: But yes, @M-M, they have the same price